# jquery forum comment reply or "quote"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create forum "quote", like reply on most of the forums but I don't know how to select items from my comment properly, and also I don't know how to select dynamically-generated IDs.

Here is my comment HTML:

```html
<div class="well well-white col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="media"> 
        <a class="pull-left" href="http://localhost/laravel/forum/public/user/5/profile">
            <img class="media-object hidden-sm" src="http://localhost/laravel/forum/public/img/avatars/U0vq13KDiPa0C4Kftr7jfdsfsdf.jpg" height="42" width="42" />
        </a>

        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading"></h4>

            <p class="text-left "> <span class="label label-black">By :</span>  <strong> <a href="http://localhost/laravel/forum/public/user/5/profile">@user</a>:</strong>

            </p>
            <div class="col-md-12 bbcomment">
                <div class="comment-body">Comment goes here</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> 
        2015-01-10 20:11:06 
        <a id="quote-4" class="btn btn-black btn-circle text-uppercase pull-right" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> quote
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my question is: how to select "comment-body" class by clicking on the link with dynamically generated ID in this case "quote-4"  so I can insert it to my textaria ( I know how to insert it, I'm just having problems with selecting the right elements and working with dynamically generated IDs )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd target a specific ancestor class. I'd also put a class on the comment links so you don't have to deal with specific IDs.

```
<a id="quote-4" class="comment-link btn btn-black...

$(".comment-link").click(function(){
    var commentBody = $(this).closest('.media').find('.comment-body');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest

http://api.jquery.com/find

Answer (score 1):

You just need to traverse the DOM (move up the chain) and find that item relative to what you have. In JQuery:

```
$("#quote-4").click(function(){
    var media_div = $($(this).parents().find(".media")[0]);
    var comment_body = $(media_div.find(".comment-body")[0]);
});
```